# Incorrect Media Query gets applied on html elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a class written for 2 set of devices(media query) iphone 6/7/8 and iphone X.

the attribute of class are similar except the measurement.

Now here, If I have written media query for iphone 6/7/8 first and media query of iphone X the last, then the media query of later one applies and same is the case if I reverse the order of those media query.Below are the details:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 812px) {
    .datepicker.dropdown-menu{
        width: 312px !important;
        /* font-family: "Avenir_Book" !important; */
        height:319px !important;
        box-shadow:none !important;
        top:305px !important;
        border-radius:16px !important;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    }

    .table-condensed {
        width: 310px !important;
    height:294px !important;
    }

    .datepicker table tr td {
        width: 30px !important;
    }

    .table-condensed tr {
        width: 255px !important;
        height: 39px;
    }

    .datepicker-days table thead {
        width: 260px !important;
    }

    .datepicker-days table tbody {
        width: 210px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 667px)  {
    .datepicker.dropdown-menu{
        width: 310px !important;
        /* font-family: "Avenir_Book" !important; */
        height:319px !important;
        box-shadow:none !important;
        top:160px !important;
        border-radius:16px !important;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    }

    .table-condensed {
        width: 308px !important;
    height:294px !important;
    }

    .datepicker table tr td {
        width: 30px !important;
    }

    .table-condensed tr {
        width: 255px !important;
        height: 39px;
    }

    .datepicker-days table thead {
        width: 260px !important;
    }

    .datepicker-days table tbody {
        width: 210px !important;
    }
}
```

I understand its the generic rule of CSS in which what comes the last will get applied unless other one is marked important. But here I have "!important" on both media queries. What should be the solution for this?

JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/2cwwe0p4/20.](http://jsfiddle.net/2cwwe0p4/20.)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, CSS works in a way from top to bottom giving last more preference over first. 
Your problem is that you need some styles to be overridden(as I have understood) for Iphone X(max-width: 812px). 
The solution could be to structure your CSS in a way that all styles are applied for "@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 812px)" and should be written first in Css file. For rest of the styles which needs to be **overwritten** for  iphone 6/7/8 (max-width: 667px) should be written below in CSS File (idea is make code generic as much possible, and change styles for Iphone 6/7/8 when max-width : 667 is reached).

Refer https://jsfiddle.net/gmbqLk5c/40/ fiddle for details.
Details are I have applied red border to table in general. But when max-width : 667px, I have overwritten the border-color: Blue. Henceforth, Iphone X will show Red border but below devices will show Blue border(without using !important).

```
<div class="container datepicker">
  <table class="mt-2 table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Sweden
        </td>
        <td>
          13:00
        </td>
         <td>
         South Korea
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Bolivia
        </td>
        <td>
          16:00
        </td>
         <td>
         Guam
        </td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>
          is
        </td>
        <td>
          23:00
        </td>
         <td>
         Hell
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>



</div>
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 812px) {

    .datepicker table tr td {
        border: solid 1px red;
     }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 667px)  {

    .datepicker table tr td {
        border: solid 1px blue;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: As suggested I removed the `!important` for `top` attribute in `.datepicker.dropdown-menu {......}` for both media queries and placed both of them in order(667px first and 812px later).. but still the `top` attribute for 812 is still getting applied on iphone 6/7/8 devices... doing the viceversa affects the iphone x the same way

Comment: I would appreciate if you could create a fiddle for your problem. Then I would be able to help you better. Additionally I just noticed you mentioned the order as (667px and then 812px). I suggested you to go ahead with 375-812px, followed by overridding styles for 667px. Please refer the media query order at https://jsfiddle.net/gmbqLk5c/40/

Comment: here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2cwwe0p4/20/.. Cannot simulate the fiddle the way I am expecting.. please have a look, also I tried the suggestion as well to reorder the sequence

Comment: I can see your styles getting changed as per media query. Though there are lot of styles so I am not sure for which you are concerned. In order to make things clearer I have added a border on dropdown menu at https://jsfiddle.net/2cwwe0p4/22/ which is blue till 667px and changes to red when width is above 667px. Please note: the style I have added is in your own list of styles to make my point more clear that your styles are also getting applied. Please revert if you still have any doubt at any other point with details

Comment: The particular attribute which is cross applied is `top` that is what creating the problem

Comment: I suppose you are concerned about following style: .datepicker.dropdown-menu{
        width: 310px !important;
        /* font-family: "Avenir_Book" !important; */
        height:319px !important;
        box-shadow:none !important;
        top:160px;
        border-radius:16px !important;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
        border: solid 1px blue;
    } If yes, then for every scenario (Iphone X or Iphone lower) your top is getting overridden by inline styles (by datepicker component ). Please confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Okay, in that scenario please apply a '!important' style with your style. It will start working as desired.Updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2cwwe0p4/25/

Comment: if this has solved your problem, Please accept the answer.